# p.adj in associate function can't be changed to p.value

Tags: r

How can i replace the p.adj.threshold by the normal pvalue and to plot it in the heatmap ? What i want it is to plot the p value and not the p.adj

```
y <- log10(abund) 
x <- as.matrix(meta)
correlations <- associate(x, y, method = "pearson", mode = "matrix", p.adj.threshold = 0.05, n.signif = 1)
correlation.table <- associate(x, y, method = "pearson", mode = "table", p.adj.threshold = 0.05, n.signif = 1) 
p <- heat(correlation.table, "X1", "X2", fill = "Correlation", star ="p.adj", p.adj.threshold =0.05)  
print(p)
```

Comment: There are multiple packages with `associate` functions. Which one are you using?

Comment: associate in microbiome package

Comment: Since both `associate` and `heat` are in the `microbiome` package, try contacting the package maintainer: 'maintainer("microbiome")' - Leo Lahti <leo.lahti@iki.fi>.